# If Select Options Equals Value Persist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to show one select field if anothers value is equal to 'document'.

```
$('#fitler-types').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'document' ){
        $('#filter-document-type').show( 'slow' );
    }
});
```

This works great but once I submit the form the values persist but the select box is hidden and will only show if I un-select document then re-select it.

Comment: What if you add the if block to the page load event?

Answer (score 0):

Just call it when you first assign the handler.

```
$('#fitler-types').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'document' ){
        $('#filter-document-type').show( 'slow' );
    }
}).change();
```

*Stack Snippet Demo*

```js
$('#fitler-types').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val("change handler called");
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fitler-types" />
```